# Making a faster parallel quicksort

Tags: c++, sorting, openmp

I'm trying to take my existing parallel Quicksort and make it execute faster. Below is what I have but half the time the optimized version doesn't give me a faster time.

I use them to compare big arrays whose sizes are 10,000 or more. Any advice on what I should change? `Nthreads` is declared in the `main` function and set to 4.

```
void quickSort_parallel_omp(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pi; 
    if (low < high)
    {
        pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        omp_set_nested(1);                               
        #pragma omp parallel sections
        {
            #pragma omp section
            quickSort_parallel_omp(arr, low, pi - 1);
            #pragma omp section
            quickSort_parallel_omp(arr, pi + 1, high);
        }
    }
}


void quickSort_Optparallel_omp(int arr[], int low, int high)   //optimized version
{
    int pi; 
    if (low < high)
    {
        pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        omp_set_nested(1);                               
        #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(Nthreads) 
        {
            #pragma omp section
            quickSort_Optparallel_omp(arr, low, pi - 1);
            #pragma omp section
            quickSort_Optparallel_omp(arr, pi + 1, high);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried benchmarking these against std::sort with a parallel execution policy?

Comment: I can't really run tests right now, but I would guess that breaking out of the parallel algorithm when `high-lo < threshold` would probably help. I would expect the task bookeeping overhead to overtake your paralelism gains at some point.

Comment: It would be nice to see the `partition()` function as that can affect the running time of quick sort.

Comment: It's not at all clear you're parallelizing your quicksort the right way. You should think about the danger of cache thrashing and memory bandwidth saturation. In fact, I would not be so sure that quicksort is the best choice for parallelization.

Comment: This code spawns two new threads on every call. Thus the number of threads spawned will approximate the size of the input. If arr[] has 4096 elements, it spawns around 4096 threads.  Did you intend to spawn at most Nthreads? I pointed this out on StackOverflow in one of the several duplicate questions you have posted, but radio silence.... Hunter - Do you copy? Calling @Hunter Davis...

Comment: You also need parallel partitioning. For instance, at the top level of recursion, partitioning is performed by a single thread only. Note that efficient paralell partitioning is anything but simple (see, e.g., implemetaion in Libstdc++ Parallel Mode).

Answer (score 2):

Nested parallelism is expensive. It was designed for around 1 nesting level when the first level is not parallel enough, and loop slicing. This kind of recursive problems are much better handled by tasks.

```
void quickSort_tasks(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pi; 
    if (low < high)
    {
        pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        #pragma omp task
        quickSort_Optparallel_omp(arr, low, pi - 1);
        #pragma omp task
        quickSort_Optparallel_omp(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

void quickSort_omp(int arr[], int low, int high) {
   #pragma omp parallel
   #pragma omp single
   quickSort_tasks(arr,low,high);
   // implicit synchronization at the end of parallel section
   // otherwise use 
   // #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

Other sorting algorithms may offer higher performance or more efficient parallelization, although being algorithmically more complex. I'm thinking about radix, pigeonhole and merge sorting.

Parallel radix sort explanation: http://projects.csail.mit.edu/wiki/pub/SuperTech/ParallelRadixSort/Fast_Parallel_Radix_Sort_Algorithm.pdf